# Set cookie for remote website

Tags: php

I succeed to use web service to login into a remote website (that I don't own), but when I refresh I lost connection. I noticed that there was a cookie for SID and when I delete it I lost connection. So I've tried to find a way to set these cookie, and I've failed. Is there so any other solution to keep connection?

```
    <?php
    setcookie("testcookie", "value1hostonly", time()+3600, "/", 
    ".freedownloadmobileringtones.com/", 0, true);


try  
{
$payload = '{
    "service":"X",
    "method":"CUS",
    "id":2,
    "params": [
        "username",
        "pwd",
        "GMT+05:00",2
    ],  "server_data":{ "sid": -1}

}';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.exemple.com.tn/services?nocache='.time());
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('    POST /services?nocache=1499940324678 HTTP/1.1',
'Host: www.exemple.com.tn',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Content-Length:'. strlen( $payload ),
'Pragma: no-cache',
'Origin: http://www.exemple.com.tn',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type: application/json',
'X-Qooxdoo-Response-Type: application/json',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Accept: */*',
'Referer: http://www.exemple.com.tn/track/',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ar;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2',
'Cookie: TawkConnectionTime='.time())

);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
header("Location:http://www.exemple.com.tn/track?nocache=".time());
$ch = curl_init();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: store the cookie locally on your server, and with the next request send along that cookie

Comment: Use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` options if you use `curl` to access the website.

Comment: @IvoP     But locally it will not be stored with the remote domain_name!

Comment: @Barmar I've tried it but doesn't worked for me

Comment: If you want help, you need to post your code.

Comment: YOU should store it. That won't go automatically. I suppose you use curl? give some code, then we can help you. Without code it will remain just suggestions what you could approx. do

Comment: I've edited the post.Take a look please.